# storing letters from text file into array

Tags: c

I am a little confused how to go through an array and add put each letter in the array `notes[]`. I am unsure what is incrementing the while loop to scan each character. I am trying to pass each character through to see if it is a letter, then capitalize it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    FILE * files;
    char notes[1000];
    int charcounter = 0, wordcounter = 0, c;
    files = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if(!files)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(files)
    {
        while(fgets(notes, sizeof notes, files) != NULL)
        {
            size_t i, n = strlen(notes);

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            {
                if(isalpha(notes[i]))
                {
                    int c = toupper(notes[i]);
                    putchar(c);
                    if(wordcounter == 50)
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                        wordcounter = 0;
                    }

                    if(charcounter == 5)
                    {
                        printf(" ");
                        charcounter = 0;
                    }
                    wordcounter++;
                    charcounter++;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    fclose(files);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I was using this a reference: 
int c;

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
if (file) {
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: you apply `toupper` and `isalpha` to a filehandle!!

Comment: Tip: For learning it is best to start with embarassingly simple tasks.  In your code, you tackle 2 different aspects: Files and arrays. Start out with a task involving only arrays. Divde and conquer ;)

Comment: I applied a file handle, am I doing something wrong? Doesn't c read each char in the file individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fgets() reads a string from a file into a char array. In your code, you read a string into the array named *notes*. You should iterate over each character in that variable, which is a C string.

Some general comments:
a) Don't return -1. Return either EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE if you want your code to be ANSI C compliant, or a positive number for POSIX platforms.

b) Use sizeof in your call to fgets() instead of hardcoding the length of the array twice.

c) isalpha(), toupper() and putchar() expects one int as argument. Your code uses a char[1000] array as argument. This should not compile without warnings/errors. (I tried, and got warnings, as expected). It's a good habit to always compile with all warnings enabled, it avoids trivial errors. If you use gcc, the options -Wall -Wextra -pedantic may be useful, at least before debugging.

Here's a stripped down version of your program, to illustrate my comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f;
    char notes[1000];

    f = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (!f) {
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(notes, sizeof notes, f) != NULL) {
        size_t i, n = strlen(notes);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int c = toupper(notes[i]);
            putchar(c);
        }
    }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you, but jw, why did you use size_t (unsigned is what I read it is) instead of int? I am assuming it just allows for more digits that are positive, correct?

Comment: *I modified the program to what you said, but it is still not working, is the while loop just there to get the entire string? if I did, 'fgets(notes, sizeof notes, f)' and didn't use a while loop, wouldn't this fill the array?

Comment: @Submersed24 : I used size_t because that's what strlen() returns.